# So I'm having a hard time understanding when to use static and when to exclude it from function headers

Tags: java, function, static, project, program-entry-point

In my introductory Java course, we are required to create a program that gets and sets info on an array of cars based off what our teacher posted on our class website. One of the requirements is to make a function that will print the info of all three cars

```html
public static void printAllCarsInfo() // function for printing info needed for all three cars
   {
      for ( int index = 0 ; index < NUM_CARS ; index++ )
         cars[index].printInfo();
```

The printInfo() function is in another class and looks like:

```html
   public void printInfo()
   {
      if ( fuelGallons > 0 )
         System.out.println("The " + getModel() + " has driven " + getMilesDriven() + " miles and has " + getFuelGallons() + " gallons left.");
      else
         System.out.println("The " + getModel() + " has driven " + getMilesDriven() + " miles and is out of gas.");
```

Now when I debug it, I get an error message that goes:

```html
Smith12.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
         cars[index].printInfo();
         ^
  symbol:   variable cars
  location: class Smith12
Smith12.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
         cars[index].drive(miles);
         ^
  symbol:   variable cars
  location: class Smith12
2 errors
```

(31 & 36 are the line numbers where the error arises)
The error comes from the for loop, but even before I switched this to a loop and just had them all listed outright, I was getting the same error. I've tried so many things that I'm just beat at this point. Someone please help me out.

Here's the main code since it isn't too long:

```html
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Smith12
{
   public static final int NUM_CARS = 3;
   
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Car[] cars = new Car[NUM_CARS];
      cars[0] = new Car( "Toyota Camry", 3400 );
      cars[1] = new Car( "Ford F-150", 5000 );
      cars[2] = new Car( "Honda Civic", 3000 );
            
      for ( int index = 0 ; index < NUM_CARS ; index++ )
         cars[index].drive(10);
      
      printAllCarsInfo();
      
      cars[0].setFuelGallons(5);
      
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("How many miles is your road trip? ");
      double roadTrip = scanner.nextDouble();
      
      driveAllCars( 10 );
      printAllCarsInfo();
   }
   public static void printAllCarsInfo() // function for printing info needed for all three cars
   {
      for ( int index = 0 ; index < NUM_CARS ; index++ )
         Car[index].printInfo();
   }
   public static void driveAllCars( double miles )
   {
      for ( int index = 0 ; index < NUM_CARS ; index++ )
         cars[index].drive(miles);
   }
}
```

And here is the Car class:

```html
public class Car
{
   private static String model;
   private static double mpg;
   private static double milesDriven;
   private static double fuelGallons;
   
   public Car( String carModel, double weight )
   {
      model = carModel;
      if ( weight > 4000 )
         mpg = 20.0;
      else
         mpg = 30.0;
      milesDriven = 7;
      fuelGallons = 15;
   }
   
   public String getModel()
   {
      return model;
   }
   
   public double getMPG()
   {
      return mpg;
   }
   
   public double getMilesDriven()
   {
      return milesDriven;
   }
   
   public double getFuelGallons()
   {
      return fuelGallons;
   }
   public void setFuelGallons( double gallons )
   {
      fuelGallons += gallons;
   }
   
   public void setMilesDriven( double distance )
   {
      milesDriven += distance;
   }
   
   public double getMilesLeft()
   {
      return mpg * fuelGallons;
   }
   
   public void drive( double miles )
   {
      if ( miles <= getMilesLeft() )
      {
         milesDriven += miles;
         fuelGallons -= ( miles / mpg );
      }
      else
      {
         milesDriven += getMilesLeft();
         fuelGallons = 0;
      }
   }
   public void printInfo()
   {
      if ( fuelGallons > 0 )
         System.out.println("The " + this.getModel() + " has driven " + this.getMilesDriven() + " miles and has " + this.getFuelGallons() + " gallons left.");
      else
         System.out.println("The " + this.getModel() + " has driven " + this.getMilesDriven() + " miles and is out of gas.");
   }
}
```

I've changed some of the variables to static, though I'm not sure it's correct. I've tried the comments but I'm here asking for help because I'm not very good at programming in general. Thank you all for your help and comments.

Comment: *function headers* ? Is this java?  Anyway all you compiler is saying is that it can not find the variable `car`

Comment: Post more code. You have a `cars` array declared someplace, I'm assuming, but the accessibility of that array to various parts of your program depends on how and where you've declared it. We need to see that code. Your entire assignment is probably not that long, so post the whole thing. And yeah... you're not working with function headers. Don't confuse yourself.

Comment: Have you tried passing the array 'cars' as an argument for the printAllCarsInfo() method?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with static vs non-static methods. My guess is that it has something to do with your misunderstanding of scoping, but you should really show more code. Where is `cars` defined? Where did you call `cars[index].printInfo()`?

Comment: I only included static in the title because I thought that was the issue. Everything was fine until I got to that step. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score -1):

In static funcions you can only use other static variables and arguments that were passed to this functions. There is no `this` context.